# nginx rewrite rule for versioned assets

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am versioning assets in my app with timestamps, so I have a `/20130705120405stylesheets/app.css` for example, and I would like to rewrite that (or any kind of other timstamp preceding stylesheets) with just `/stylesheets/app.css`.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write a rewrite rule to ignore the timestamp

```
rewrite "/[0-9]{14}stylesheets/app.css" /stylesheets/app.css break;
```